# ViewModel updates interrupts user interaction with bound TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, wcf-binding

I'm having a problem where user input is interrupted by updates from the bound ViewModel.

The ViewModel exposes a numerical value **which changes each second.** This is bound to a `TextBox` in the view. We want the `TextBox` to display this value, which it does well.

However, when the user clicks on the `TextBox` and tries to enter a new value, the value in the model gets updated which causes the user-entered value in the textbox to be overwritten.

How can I most easily solve this issue, supporting user input and regular updates in the same control? I would appreciate code examples (C# / XAML).

If you need more details just ask :)

Comment: I think that's a bit clearer.  The "easy" solution is to bind the display value not to a TextBox but another control.  For example, a Label associated with that TextBox.  Otherwise you'll need a custom UserControl or Control, as the desired behavior you're looking for isn't available in any controls within the framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When TextBox gets focus (IsFocused property equals true) I change binding type so that it would not be updated unless it looses focus.

 **ViewModel:**

```
 class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                Debug.WriteLine(value);
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
                {

                    Name = i.ToString();
                    await Task.Delay(3000);
                }
            });
        }


        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox>
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsFocused}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
       </TextBox>
    <Button Content="Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

I got sequence 2,3 then I inputed 56 and clicked Button so textbox lost focus and sent value to Name property. Debug printed following sequence:

1
2
3
56
4

Comment: Thanks for the input - it was very close to what I wanted. I tweaked your solution, and instead of using IsFocused, I introduced a boolean property named EditMode, which will change the binding similar to your solution. Thanks for the input Maximus!